# How to calculate life expectancy of the astronauts?

Tags: survival, actuarial-science

I'm trying to obtain a more authoritative answer to the question: [Do astronauts live longer than earthlings?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29538/)

While the time dilation thing has been easily dismissed as it introduces negligible milliseconds of lifetime extension, the hypothesis is based on the process of selection for the job of an astronaut: exceptional individuals of exquisite health and fitness, living healthy, fit lifestyle under excellent health care. That *should* correlate with lifespan longer than average - not *caused* by being astronauts, just a common root for the two. On the other hand, it's a dangerous job with deadly accidents, and the radiation exposure does lead to serious health problems. I'd like to find which of these factors is stronger.

---

To show my work so far - it was rather simple, and with serious flaws, but it already showed promise to proving the hypothesis. Using the  Using the [list of space travelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_travelers_by_name) I averaged lifespan and birth dates of all space travelers deceased to date. Average birth year: 1937; average lifespan: 61.4 years. Only two of the 79 entries were women, so the result predominantly favors men; [US life expectancy](http://www.demog.berkeley.edu/~andrew/1918/figure2.html) for 1937 was 58.0 years. I couldn't find life expectancy in Soviet Union, but I [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_Soviet_Union#Life_expectancy_and_infant_mortality) it only exceeded the US value in 1960's. My figure also excludes astronauts still alive, who currently exceed average life expectancy for their age, making my "61.4" a bottom cap, and 3.4 year the least life expectancy difference between a Joe Average, and an astronaut.

---

Still, this is heavily flawed as it's based on life expectancy at birth. It would be much more telling, if I could compare the figures for expectancy at age of 35 (the average age of selection - becoming an astronaut; the general life expectancy at birth includes all deaths up to that age), use some more intelligent comparison than averaging birthdates and picking that singular year, and not ignore these still alive!

I've managed to find a [spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AonYZs4MzlZbdG1JQklzbDB5aGdqbktscjZndHRmU3c&hl=en_US) with all astronauts to date, with birth dates; I can add all the known death dates wherever applicable. That should be sufficient to find a better answer to the problem - if I knew how to approach it correctly from mathematical standpoint. The Wikipedia article on [Life Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_table#The_mathematics) tells how to use one, not how to build one. The article on [Life Expectancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_expectancy#Calculation) gives a bit of mathematics for large populations, but only skims the surface about using Life Tables, and forecasting (which likely should be applied to the alive part of the population.) -

So, my questions would be:

- does my adjusted plan (values of life expectancy at 35 over time, comparison according to more generally accepted methods of comparing life expectancies of populations) make sense to confirm the hypothesis? Or did I miss some more crucial details and it's still heavily flawed?
- How to calculate these?
- How to compare to general population data?